# How to implement custom naming for multioutput primitives in FeatureTools

Tags: python, primitive, featuretools

As of version v0.12.0, FeatureTools allows you to assign custom names to multi-output primitives: https://github.com/alteryx/featuretools/pull/794. By default, the when you define custom multi-output primitives, the column names for the generated features are appended with a `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. So let us say that I have the following code to output a multi-output primitive:

```
def sine_and_cosine_datestamp(column):
    """
    Returns the Sin and Cos of the hour of datestamp
    """
    sine_hour = np.sin(column.dt.hour)
    cosine_hour = np.cos(column.dt.hour)
    
    ret = [sine_hour, cosine_hour]
    return ret

Sine_Cosine_Datestamp = make_trans_primitive(function = sine_and_cosine_datestamp,
                                             input_types = [vtypes.Datetime],
                                             return_type = vtypes.Numeric,
                                             number_output_features = 2)
```

In the dataframe generated from DFS, the names of the two generated columns will be `SINE_AND_COSINE_DATESTAMP(datestamp)[0]` and `SINE_AND_COSINE_DATESTAMP(datestamp)[1]`. In actuality, I would have liked the names of the columns to reflect the operations being taken on the column. So I would have liked the column names to be something like `SINE_AND_COSINE_DATESTAMP(datestamp)[sine]` and `SINE_AND_COSINE_DATESTAMP(datestamp)[cosine]`. Apparently you have to use the `generate_names` method in order to do so. I could not find anything online to help me use this method and I kept running into errors. For example, when I tried the following code:

```
def sine_and_cosine_datestamp(column, string = ['sine, cosine']):
    """
    Returns the Sin and Cos of the hour of the datestamp
    """
    sine_hour = np.sin(column.dt.hour)
    cosine_hour = np.cos(column.dt.hour)
    
    ret = [sine_hour, cosine_hour]
    return ret

def sine_and_cosine_generate_names(self, base_feature_names):
    return u'STRING_COUNT(%s, "%s")' % (base_feature_names[0], self.kwargs['string'])

Sine_Cosine_Datestamp = make_trans_primitive(function = sine_and_cosine_datestamp,
                                             input_types = [vtypes.Datetime],
                                             return_type = vtypes.Numeric,
                                             number_output_features = 2,
                                             description = "For each value in the base feature"
                                             "outputs the sine and cosine of the hour, day, and month.",
                                             cls_attributes = {'generate_names': sine_and_cosine_generate_names})
```

I had gotten an assertion error. What's even more perplexing to me is that when I went into the `transform_primitve_base.py` file found in the `featuretools/primitives/base` folder, I saw that the `generate_names` function looks like this:

```
    def generate_names(self, base_feature_names):
        n = self.number_output_features
        base_name = self.generate_name(base_feature_names)
        return [base_name + "[%s]" % i for i in range(n)]
```

In the function above, it looks like there is no way that you can generate custom primitive names since it uses the `base_feature_names` and the number of output features by default. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question!  This feature hasn't been documented well.

The main issue with your code was that `string_count_generate_name` should return a list of strings, one for each column.

It looks like you were adapting the `StringCount` example from the docs -- I think for this primitive it would be less error-prone to always use "sine" and "cosine" for the custom names, and remove the optional `string` argument from `sine_and_cosine_datestamp`. I also updated the feature name text to match your desired text.

After these changes:

```
def sine_and_cosine_datestamp(column):
    """
    Returns the Sin and Cos of the hour of the datestamp
    """
    sine_hour = np.sin(column.dt.hour)
    cosine_hour = np.cos(column.dt.hour)
    
    ret = [sine_hour, cosine_hour]
    return ret

def sine_and_cosine_generate_names(self, base_feature_names):
    template = 'SINE_AND_COSINE_DATESTAMP(%s)[%s]'
    return [template % (base_feature_names[0], string) for string in ['sine', 'cosine']]
```

This created feature column names like `SINE_AND_COSINE_DATESTAMP(order_date)[sine]`.   No changes were necessary to the actual `make_trans_primitive` call.

> In the function above, it looks like there is no way that you can generate custom primitive names since it uses the base_feature_names and the number of output features by default.

That is the default `generate_names` function for transform primitives.  Since we are assigning this custom generate names function to `Sine_Cosine_Datestamp` , the default will not be used.

Hope that helps, let me know if you still have questions!

Comment: Ah yes haha you noticed I did adapt the `StringCount` example. Also thank you for answering my question so clearly and easy for me to understand. I spent so much time combing through the .py files in Featuretools. Thanks again!!